# java.io: Rename all elements of an absolute File path

Tags: java, io, directory, file-rename

I am writing a little tool for "normalizing" file and directory names to make them safe for portability, interoperability and general reduction of stupid and painful errors due to file names with non-ASCII characters, spaces and other evil characters etc. (see [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/748264/472755) for a concise summary of the few truly safe characters).

To do that, I want to rename an file/directory with an unsafe name to a safe name, **including** renaming all parent directories accordingly. Shouldn't be a problem, even with `java.io` that I need to use; however I cannot seem to rename directories containing other directories (containing files works fine).

This is my method:

```
public static File renameSafe(File unsafe) throws IOException {
    if (!unsafe.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(unsafe.toString());
    }

    // create full "safe" path
    File safe = toSafeFile(unsafe);
    File origSafe = safe;

    while (unsafe != null) {
        // rename the lowest unsafe level
        File unsafeParent = unsafe.getParentFile();
        File safeTarget = new File(unsafeParent, safe.getName());
        if (!unsafe.renameTo(safeTarget)) {
            throw new IOException("Could not rename " + unsafe + " to " + safe);
        }

        unsafe = unsafeParent;
        safe = safe.getParentFile();
    }

    return origSafe;
}
```

When I run this main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("\\test\\-bad.folder NAME ÄÖÜßéÂÌ\\.bad folder 2\\test filename-ÄÖÜ.txt");
    System.out.println(file);
    System.out.println(toSafeFileName(file));
    renameSafe(file);
}
```

I get the following output:

```
\test\-bad.folder NAME ÄÖÜßéÂÌ\.bad folder 2\test filename-ÄÖÜ.txt
\test\_bad_folder_name_aou-eai\_bad_folder_2\test_filename-aou.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Could not rename \test\-bad.folder NAME ÄÖÜßéÂÌ to \test\_bad_folder_name_aou-eai
    at SafeFileName.renameSafe(SafeFileName.java:77)
    at SafeFileName.main(SafeFileName.java:90)
```

The first two levels, everything is renamed as is; reaching the leaf file's grandparent, `renameTo()` suddenly returns `false`.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong? I tried with other file names (including with 100% input file names), but it always seems that `File.renameTo()` can not seem to rename directories containing other directories. However, my personal bet would be some stupidity of myself, paired with some obscure API details.

#### EDIT:

Okay, here's the SSCCE:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RenameTest
{
    public static File toSafeFileName(File file) {
        File safe = new File(file.getName().replace("bad", "good"));

        for (;;) {
            file = file.getParentFile();
            if (file == null) {
                return safe;
            }

            if (file.toString().equals(File.separator)) {
                safe = new File("", safe.getPath());
            } else {
                safe = new File(
                        file.getName().replace("bad", "good"),
                        safe.getPath());
            }
        }
    }

    public static File renameSafe(File unsafe) throws IOException {
        if (!unsafe.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(unsafe.toString());
        }

        File safe = toSafeFileName(unsafe);
        File origSafe = safe;

        while (unsafe != null && !unsafe.equals(safe)) {
            File unsafeParent = unsafe.getParentFile();
            File safeTarget = new File(unsafeParent, safe.getName());

            System.out.print(unsafe + " -> " + safeTarget + "? ");

            if (unsafe.renameTo(safeTarget)) {
                System.out.println("OK.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error!");
                throw new IOException();
            }

            unsafe = unsafeParent;
            safe = safe.getParentFile();
        }

        return origSafe;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File unsafePath = new File("\\test\\bad1\\bad2\\bad.txt");
        if (!unsafePath.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
            throw new IOException("can't create " + unsafePath.getParentFile());
        }
        if (!unsafePath.createNewFile()) {
            throw new IOException("can't create dummy file");
        }

        File safePath = renameSafe(unsafePath);
        if (safePath.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Renamed " + unsafePath + " to " + safePath);
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Safe path " + safePath + " does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

On first run, with a clean `D:\test` directory, everything runs fine:

```
\test\bad1\bad2\bad.txt -> \test\bad1\bad2\good.txt? OK.
\test\bad1\bad2 -> \test\bad1\good2? OK.
\test\bad1 -> \test\good1? OK.
Renamed \test\bad1\bad2\bad.txt to \test\good1\good2\good.txt
```

So OK, Java *can* rename directories containing directories.

BUT, on the second run (without cleaning `D:\test` first), I get the following:

```
\test\bad1\bad2\bad.txt -> \test\bad1\bad2\good.txt? OK.
\test\bad1\bad2 -> \test\bad1\good2? OK.
\test\bad1 -> \test\good1? Error!
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException
    at funky.core.io.RenameTest2.renameSafe(RenameTest2.java:46)
    at funky.core.io.RenameTest2.main(RenameTest2.java:65)
```

So it seems that the problems really was I didn't clean up my test directory, and that Java can't rename a directory to an already existing directory -- as the `good1` was already created on the first run... As this is stated in the `renameTo()` API, this was indeed just my own stupidity. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Check to see if the `parent` directory still exists, it may have already been renamed.  I'd rename the directory first, the process it's contents, rather then trying to update the parent

Comment: Nope, parent directory exists fine. Going top-down instead of bottom-up sounds good, but I'd still like to know why doing it bottom-up shouldn't work.

Comment: Have a look at your output, `\test\-bad.folder NAME ÄÖÜßéÂÌ to \test\_bad_folder_name_aou-eai`, the directory `\test\-bad.folder NAME ÄÖÜßéÂÌ` has already been renamed in the previous line, so Java is thinking, "I have no idea where this directory is any more...oh crap!!?" (or at least I am)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, this...

```
File unsafeParent = unsafe.getParentFile();
File safeTarget = new File(unsafeParent, safe.getName());
```

So, using `\test\-bad.folder NAME ÄÖÜßéÂÌ\.bad folder 2\test filename-ÄÖÜ.txt` as the base path, `unsafeParent` would equal `\test\-bad.folder NAME ÄÖÜßéÂÌ\.bad folder 2`, but `safeTarget` is now `unsafeParent + safe.getName()`, so you're not trying to rename the directory, but a file in `unsafeParent` named `safe.getName()`...

Instead of working bottom up, work top down.  This means you can rename the directory and using the renamed reference, list the files in it and process them.

Comment: Thanks for the File I/O basics, but I think you're confused by the first two lines of my output. They only represent current and target names, nothing has been renamed there. Particularly not some parent directory; I work bottom up, it's the lower directories which are renamed first (first `test filename-ÄÖÜ.txt`, followed by `.bad folder 2\`). And as I said, my problem is not to rename a directory with files in it, but a directory with a *subdirectory* in it.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses.  Directory with files in it is pretty much the same thing as a directory with sub directories.  A directory is just a special type of file

Comment: @FranzD. Without a running example, I'm guessing that the update is closer to your issue...

Comment: I provided a running example, and while developing it, I realized that it was all a silly mistake of my part. I edited the question to include the SSCCE and apologize for wasting your time, @MadProgrammer...